# Positioning on navbar

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar with some links on it and a header, just like bootstrap, but I'm trying to make it so the account dropdown is on the right side, but when I add the class "pullRight" it moves it to the right but doesn't stay on the navigation bar.

[image: Screenshot]

pullright CSS

```
.pullRight {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Players</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shop</a></li>
    <li class="pullRight"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Navigation bar CSS

```
.navigationBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%, #d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#efefef), color-stop(100%,#d3d3d3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EB7727;
}
.navigationBar ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navigationBar ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%, #d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#efefef), color-stop(100%,#d3d3d3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EB7727;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navigationBar ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
.navigationBar ul li:hover {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(211,211,211); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%, rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(211,211,211,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(239,239,239,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(211,211,211,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3d3d3', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navigationBar ul li a ,
.navigationBar ul li a:hover ,
.navigationBar ul li a:active {
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully this helps. all i have done is added the float left to all other menu options except accounts... i also added padding 0 to the ul element to remove the leading space before forums..

```css
    
    .navigationBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%, #d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#efefef), color-stop(100%,#d3d3d3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EB7727;
}
.navigationBar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.navigationBar ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%, #d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#efefef), color-stop(100%,#d3d3d3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #efefef 50%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EB7727;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navigationBar ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.navigationBar ul li:last-child {
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
.navigationBar ul li:hover {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(211,211,211); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%, rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(211,211,211,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(239,239,239,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(211,211,211,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(211,211,211,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 50%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3d3d3', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navigationBar ul li a ,
.navigationBar ul li a:hover ,
.navigationBar ul li a:active {
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pullRight{
    float:right;
}
.pullLeft{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationBar">
<ul>
    <li class="pullLeft"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Forums</a></li>
    <li class="pullLeft"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Players</a></li>
    <li class="pullLeft"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shop</a></li>
    <li class="pullRight"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking to do...have a gr8 day

Comment: +1 - I would simplify it slightly - `.navigationBar ul li { float: left; } .navigationBar ul li:last-child { float: right; }` float them all to the left except the last one which will be floated right. No need for classes in your HTML :)

Comment: @misterManSam I agree with you. I was not thinking that. I knew what the problem was as soon as I saw the screenshot that OP posted. So I just did the most minimal work lol thanks for that catch

Answer (score 0):

```
pullRight
```

Should be

```
.pullRight
```

In your CSS file

Comment: Anything else I could do?